# mixed content - mshots

Tags: php, wordpress

Since my website moved to https, I see I have a lot of mixed content because of the mshots snippet.

In `includes/functions.php` I tried to change the URL from `http://s0.wordpress.com/mshots/v1` to `https://s0.wordpress.com/mshots/v1`, but then I have a new issue : half of my images disappear.

If I try to add a new shop to my site, there is no image, so it is not only affecting half of my existing stores, but also every new store I add.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: What does the web developer console (F12 on chrome and firefox) tells you?

Comment: The console tells "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"

Comment: Yeah, tell the website administrator (of those external images) to resolve that issue. There's nothing you can do - unless you want to do use an image proxy on your server to load the images through HTTP by the proxy and let the browser load them as HTTPS through the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have valid SSL certificate, than just move whole website on https, you can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, put this code to your .htaccess. Now every thing go to your server will be force redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: We did this when we moved to https, everything is fine and correctly except the images which are loaded with the mshots snippet. It creates a screenshot of a website and loads as a featured image on our site, but until I don't change the code to https, I will still have mixed content, and if I change half of the images will make a 403 error.